# $L^2$ space with values in vector bundle.

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-bundles, bochner-spaces

Let $E$ be a vector bundle over $S^2$ with inner product, $\pi$ its bundle projection and each fiber has dimension $m$.

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R^n}$. Consider space of all square integrable functions $f$ from $\Omega\times S^2$ to $E$ i.e.
$$
\|f\|^2 = \int_{\Omega \times S^2} \| f(x,\omega) \|^2_{\pi(x,\omega)} \, dx \, d\omega < \infty
$$
such that $f(x,\omega) \in \pi^{-1}(\omega)$ for all $\omega \in S^2$. Thanks to this condition the space is a vector space. Denote this space $\mathcal{L}^2(\Omega\times S^2,E)$.

> Is this space $\mathcal{L}^2(\Omega\times S^2,E)$ any different to the standard vector valued Lebesgue space $L^2(\Omega\times S^2,\mathbb{R}^m)$ ?

My guess is no, because it really does not care about the topology of $E$.

If they are different where I can read more about such space?

Comment: Could you please explain how (or if) you're identifying a section of $E$ with an $\mathbf{R}^{m}$-valued function on $\Omega \times S^{2}$?

Comment: All integrable functions *together* fail to be a vector space. For simplicity regard $\pi:\Omega:=[0,1]\to\mathbb{C}=:E$. Then for $f:=1$ and $g:=2-1_\mathbb{V}$ one has $\|f\|,\|g\|\in\mathcal{B}([0,1],\mathbb{C})$ but $\|2f-g\|\notin\mathcal{B}([0,1],\mathbb{C})$.